# rviz installation issues on 64bit snow-leopard using ROS Diamondback

Tags: rviz, macos-snowleopard, ros-diamondback, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install rviz on ROS Diamondback (on a 64 bit Mac Snowleopard). I get this link error related to Ogre::Rectancle2D when I run,

"rosmake rviz"

Error mesg:

Undefined symbols:

"Ogre::Rectangle2D::Rectangle2D(bool)", referenced from: rviz::SelectionManager::initialize()      in selection_manager.o

Any idea why it cant find the Rectangle2D symbol (specifically) in Ogre ?

When I comment all the occurrences of Rectangle2D (jus to see it build completely! ) and run it using,

"rosrun rviz rviz"

It complains that it cant find the Ogre library.

Error msg:

dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Ogre.framework/Versions/1.7.2/Ogre

I have built Ogre 1.7.2 manually (as the 1.7.1 version which comes with ROS does not build on 64 bit).

Can anyone tell me where exactly do I need to put the Ogre libraries for rviz to work ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9209/rviz-installation-issues-on-64bit-snow-leopard-using-ros-diamondback/) by [Sagnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/183/sagnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2011-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since `rviz` depends on the `ogre` ROS package, the libraries and headers need to be there.

Have you tried building the `ogre` package with 1.7.2 instead? If it can be done, that should work.

This sounds like a bug to me, worth opening a defect ticket on the Ogre version.

```
Also, I am not able to understand what exactly you mean by,

    Have you tried building the ogre package with 1.7.2 instead ?

I have manually built OGRE 1.7.2 as the default version which comes with ROS 
Diamondback is 1.7.1 and does not build on Mac Snowleopard 64 bit.
```

I was hoping you could fix the ROS ogre package to use 1.7.2 instead. Building it manually does not help. We need a solution that works for all 64-bit OSX users.

You probably don't know how to do that, so please open up a ticket so the package maintainers will know about this problem. They should be able to fix it for you.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0